# Problemas con rutas en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Tengo los siguientes codigos:

Tengo mi index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include('includes/head.php');?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include('includes/navbar.php');?>
    <?php include('includes/footer.php');?>
</body>
</html>
```

head.php

```
   <title>Titulo</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.dataTables.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

footer.php

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/estilos.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="js/buttons.js"></script>
<script src="js/html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/row.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/listaSoftware.js"></script>
```

Tambien tengo un navbar pero no tiene caso ponerlo aqui.

Todo esto funciona en el index, pero si creo una carpeta llamada views y creo un archivo home.php y

home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include('../includes/head.php');?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include('../includes/navbar.php');?>
    <?php include('../includes/footer.php');?>
</body>
</html>
```

Este home encuentra el head y footer pero estos ya no encuentran los JSy CSS.
Mi directorio

```
-css

-js

-includes
   --footer.php
   --navbar.php
   --head.php
-view

   --home.php

index.php
```

Por ejemplo el Index funciona bien, pero cuando quiero llamar a home.php que esta dentro de la carpeta view no me encuentra las rutas de los js y css.

En que estoy fallando y espero haberme explicado bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al estar en la carpeta view, el interprete espera que los archivos javascript estén en `example.com/view/js/...`

Puedes declarar el `src` de los scripts para que apunten siempre a la raiz, de esta forma

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/estilos.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="/js/buttons.js"></script>
<script src="/js/html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/row.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/listaSoftware.js"></script>
```

Y lo mismo con los css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/estilos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/estilos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de hacer el `<?php include('../includes/footer.php');?>` en `home.php` busca los directorios dentro de la carpeta `view` por ejemplo `<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` esta buscando dentro de la carpeta en la cual estos directorios no existen, para poder acceder tienes que salir un directorio por ejemplo `<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` como solución puedes tener dos archivos `footer.php y footer2.php` ya que al realizar el include toma la ruta en la cual fue incluido el fichero

Comment: Si hago <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> no me los reconoce el index.php

Comment: Es inapropiado tener varios archivos solo para cambiar una ruta, en este caso se necesita un archivo de configuración.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso lo ideal es tener un archivo de configuración que indique el `BASE_DIR` (directorio base del proyecto) y el `BASE_URL` (base de las rutas desde el navegador).

~/config.php

```
<?php

/** Ruta del proyecto */
declare('BASE_DIR', __DIR__);

/** Ruta en el navegador */
declare('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/nombre-proyecto');
```

> Es por que la rutas se llamen haciendo referencia al archivo actual por esta razón se le deben anteponer a las rutas la constante predefinida de PHP `__DIR__` de lo contrario comenzaría la ruta desde donde se incluye el archivo.

[Constantes predefinidas en PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php)

Incluir el archivo de configuración desde cada uno de los archivos, la ruta se debe escribir según el nivel de carpetas donde se encuentre, así:

~/index.php

`require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';`

~/view/home.php
~/includes/*.php

`require_once __DIR__ . '/../config.php';`

---

Cambiar las rutas PHP (desde cualquier archivo que incluya el config.php)

```
include BASE_DIR . '/includes/navbar.php';
include BASE_DIR . '/includes/head.php';
include BASE_DIR . '/includes/footer.php';
```

Cambiar las rutas HTML (debe incluir el archivo config.php)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= BASE_URL . '/css/estilos.css' ?>">

<script src="<?= BASE_URL ?>/js/listaSoftware.js"></script>
```

> Las rutas con la figura `<?= BASE_URL ?>` solo funcionan si se tienen activos los `short_open_tag` de lo contrario se debe reemplazar por `<?php echo BASE_URL ?>`